# Jquery Datatable null column

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi i have created the jquery datatable using below code..

The column email id and activated date is may be nullable. When i render the table it is showing 'Request unknown parameter 'email' from data source for row 0'

```
 var tblAllKeys = $('#tblAllKeys').dataTable({
                    "bDestroy" : true,
                    "bProcessing" : true,
                    "bServerSide" : true,
                    "bLenthChange" : false,
                    "iDisplayLength" : 10,
                    "sAjaxSource" : "loadAllKeys",
                    "oLanguage" : {
                        "sSearch" : "Search By Activation Key:"
                    },
                    "aoColumns" : [
                     {"sTitle" : "No.","mData" : null,"aTargets": [ 0 ],
                        "fnRender" : function(obj) {
                            var columnIndex = obj.oSettings._iDisplayStart + obj.iDataRow+1
                            return columnIndex;
                        }
                    },
                    {"sTitle" : "Activation Key","mData" : "key", "bSearchable" : true},
                    {"sTitle" : "Email ID","mData" :  "email" , "bSearchable" : false},
                    {"sTitle" : "App Edition","mData" : "edition", "bSearchable" : false},
                    {"sTitle" : "Batch Code","mData" : "batch", "bSearchable" : false},
                    {"sTitle" : "Activated Date","mData" : "aDate" , "bSearchable" : false},
                    {"sTitle" : "Generated Date","mData" : "gDate", "bSearchable" : false},
                    {"sTitle" : "Status","mData" : "status", "bSearchable" : false},
                    ],
                       "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                        $.ajax({
                         "dataType" : 'json',
                         "type" : "GET",
                         "url" : sSource,
                         "data" : aoData,
                         "success" : fnCallback
                        });
                       },
                       "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
                });
```

Comment: `nullable` or the column itself will not be present?

Comment: no column is present. only value is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of **[`columns.defaultContent`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent)** option available as per their **[docs on this error](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4)**, to display default value or empty string when column's doesn't have any value.

```
"aoColumns": [{
  "sTitle": "No.",
  "mData": null,
  "aTargets": [0],
  "fnRender": function(obj) {
    var columnIndex = obj.oSettings._iDisplayStart + obj.iDataRow + 1
    return columnIndex;
  }
}, {
  "sTitle": "Activation Key",
  "mData": "key",
  "bSearchable": true
}, {
  "sTitle": "Email ID",
  "defaultContent":"",//or specify any other value
  "mData": "email",
  "bSearchable": false
}, {
  "sTitle": "App Edition",
  "mData": "edition",
  "bSearchable": false
}, {
  "sTitle": "Batch Code",
  "mData": "batch",
  "bSearchable": false
}, {
  "sTitle": "Activated Date",
  "mData": "aDate",
  "bSearchable": false
}, {
  "sTitle": "Generated Date",
  "mData": "gDate",
  "bSearchable": false
}, {
  "sTitle": "Status",
  "mData": "status",
  "bSearchable": false
}, ],
```

Its good to assign `defaultContent` option to all the columns if you are sure that any of the `column` might come empty.

Comment: Could you please try replicating it here with sample data?

Comment: Do you mean the response from server?

Comment: `{"iTotalRecords":0,"iTotalDisplayRecords":0,"sEcho":2,"aaData":[{"key":"JPBFTU3Q1MOY","edition":"Professional Edition","batch":"PROMOTIONAL TRIAL KEYS 1","gDate":"05/11/2016","status":"Unsubscribed"}]}`

Comment: Your `aaData` does not contain `email id` column?

Comment: I think i know what the issue is. i'm not sending email from server.

Comment: Yes, that's what my first question was.. `email id` column is present in your response data?